# Do I have to have two repositories for my Apache web server to avoid my php files being in the root path?

Tags: git, apache, github, webserver, apache2

So, I am trying to keep my PHP files that handle user data stored in a DB out of the root path of my Apache web server "/var/www/html", I do understand that this adds an extra security layer to my server.

Let's say I have a repository called "front-end" and another called "back-end", but what if I have multiple websites? Do I have to have two repositories for each of them?

Is this a normal practice in production?

I do Have two repositories but I feel that if you have multiple websites that may cause having a lot of files and repositories instead of having just one repository for each website.

My expectation is to have just one repository and be able to have my front-end files on the root path of my Apache web server and my PHP files in other path location.

**If all of what I am trying is not a normal practice. What is the normal practice to keep your PHP files out of the user or possibly an attacker? Let's say an user that enters in the address bar [www.mywebsite.com/log-in.php](http://www.mywebsite.com/log-in.php) (trying to see how the code works)**

Comment: I do not feel there is any increased security in storing PHP files in a special directory. The key is to write the code in PHP files correctly. In your last example for a correctly configured server, a user cannot see the code. The server would load `log-in.php` and execute it. If that is a submodule of only functions, nothing should or will happen. If your server has been breached, if a page can reach the PHP files located in a special directory, so can the hacker. However, there are many factors to consider. Rewrite your post and show an example with code, type of security breach, etc.